# Could not load library "C:\...\ rtpostgis-2.2.dll"

Tags: postgis, postgresql, windows

I've installed PostgreSQL with Postgis (tried both version 9.4 and 9.5 ) on a remote desktop running Windows 7 64bit.

However, when I executed this SQL command: "CREATE EXTENSION postgis" (on PgAdmin run as administrator), this message came up:

> ERROR:  could not load library
>   "C:/PostgreSQL9_5/lib/rtpostgis-2.2.dll": The specified procedure
>   could not be found.
>
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: could not load library
>   "C:/PostgreSQL9_5/lib/rtpostgis-2.2.dll": The specified procedure
>   could not be found. SQL state: XX000

I can confirm that "rtpostgis-2.2.dll" was there.

Please tell me how to fix this. It's so frustrating to uninstall and then reinstall every time but the problem still persisted.

P/s: On my Home PC running Windows 10 64bit, PostgreSQL is running like a charm. Postgis and Pgrouting extension can be created easily.

Comment: Are you able to connect to a psql session on the remote machine. I am wondering if it is a permissions issue.

Comment: Did you mean "using psql in command line?". Actually I tried connecting to the database by using command line but it just gave a error message, kind of "psql not recognizable".

Comment: I did mean that, yes. It is likely, as it is a remote machine, that the you don't have the path to the Postgres executables set as an environment variable. Try `echo %PATH%` in a cmd prompt on remote machine. If that does not contain a path to the Postgres binaries, then either add it, or run `CREATE EXTENSION postgis` from that location.

Comment: I've tried:: 1-Add PATH to Postgres bin folder -> Still no use////  2-Install PostgreSQL 9.3 and run cmd from bin folder, using psql to "create extension postgis" -> the same error occured. On this remote desktop (a virtual machine run on server), I've once succeeded in install PostgreSQL 9.4, create postgis ext and...., everything was fine, until I upgrade this to version 9.5.

Comment: I am also having same problem. Seems like something wrong with 95

Comment: Same problem on XP64 with postgresql-9.5.2-1-windows-x64.exe, 9.4.4-3 was still working

Comment: In my case, even I've remove the 9.5 version and reinstalled the older ones, the problem was still there :(

Comment: Using the @LR123567's suggestion fixed the issue for me!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect you are running the latest PostgreSQL Patch released yesterday.  I have confirmed an incompatiblity issue with latest release OpenSSL and the libcurl we ship - detailed here - http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/364-PostGIS-2.2-Windows-users-hold-off-on-installing-latest-PostgreSQL-patch-release.html

We have compiled a new version of curl compiled with same version of OpenSSL that ships with PostgreSQL 9.5.2.

http://winnie.postgis.net/download/windows/pg95/buildbot/libcurl7.48withsslx64.zip

Replace your libcurl-4.dll with the one in this zip and it should resolve your problems.

Comment: I had the same issue (Win7 x64) and I can confirm that the substitution fix the issue!

Comment: I ran into the same problem when installing postgis from the Application Stack Builder and this dll fixed the issue, but I had some difficulty getting it to work. The issue was that I could put the patched file in, but it would get overwritten again with the incompatible version when I tried to do the install.

During the install it pauses to ask a few yes/no options, at that point I could paste the patched version in and it would work. Hopefully that helps if anyone else is running into the same issue.

Comment: I just put up PostGIS 2.2.2 on Application Stackbuilder for PostgreSQL 9.5 (x32/x64).  These have the fixes, so for future people having this issue, just install the lastst from Stackbuilder.  Can also get from http://postgis.net/windows_downloads/  The binaries for other versions should work too but haven't packaged installers for others yet.

Comment: I am having the same issue running postgres 9.3 and postgis 2.2. I replaced the libcurl-4.dll with the one you provided, but I am still getting the same error? And the rtpostgis-2.2.dll is in the location where it says it can't be found.

Comment: That's the wrong one for 9.3.  I haven't released 9.3 2.2.2 stackbuilder yet - but you can pull the curl from binaries - http://winnie.postgis.net/download/windows/pg93/buildbot/postgis-pg93-binaries-2.2.2w64gcc48.zip which is in folder:  http://winnie.postgis.net/download/windows/pg93/buildbot/ (if you replacea ll teh files, you'll have PostGIS 2.2.2